# Missing assembly when running tests with mstest from the command line for a .net core project

Tags: command-line, mstest, asp.net-core-1.0

I am currently creating a CI build plan for a new project we are building using .net core and I am running into some issues running the tests.

When I attempt to run the tests from the command window I get the following problem:

c:>mstest.exe /testcontainer:CommonCore.Tests.dll

Loading CommonCore.Tests.dll...
CommonCore.Tests.dll
Unable to load the test container 'CommonCore.Tests.dll' or one of its dependencies. Error details: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I have included 'System.Runtime' to the dependencies of the project but that seems to have no effect.

[image]

Has anyone run into this issue and found a solution?

Comment: The same error is present when using Debug Test within VS 2015.

Answer (score 2):

Please use `dotnet test` to run tests for .net core. Or use `vstest.console project.json` if you're using VS 2015 Update 3 with dotnet sdk.

If your test project has a `net46` target framework, mstest.exe may work. It uses the system wide .net runtime to invoke the test container.

Comment: Thanks. I did a little more research because I need the test result file to be generated to report on the build process and found out that you can use this command to test .net core projects using vstest.console.exe

**vstest.console.exe project.json /logger:trx**

Comment: Good find. Updated answer.

Comment: While this provides an alternate method, it does not really answer the question.